# Show that $C$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$, where $C=\{c_z(w)\mid w\text{ is in the interior of } \triangle^m\}$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $Y$ be a semi-simplical set and $|Y|$ it's geometric realisation. Fix an $m\ge0$ and an $m$-simplex $z\in Y_m$. Define $C\subset |Y|$ by $C=\{c_z(w)\mid w\text{ is in the interior of } \triangle^m\}$, where $c_z:\triangle^m\to|Y|$ is the characteristic map associated with the simplex $z\in Y_m$. Show that $C$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$.

What I have come up with so far is that for $m=1$, $\triangle^1$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$. So, if we split $[0,1]$ in $u_0, u_1, u_2$ and $u_3$ and use that the union of $u_0, u_1, u_2$ and $u_3$ can be again extended to cover $[0,1]$ and then use the fact that $[0,1]$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

But I don't know how to proceed to prove it for $m>1$.